# Azure BotFrameworkAdapter Error 400 missing parameter type

Tags: node.js, linux, azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

I've deploy my node.js server into Azure by new AppService linux.
It correctly start, because if I call one http get it return the correct data.
But when I try to call the post url that make a:

```
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (context) => {
    // Process bot activity
    await botActivityHandler.run(context).catch((e) => { console.dir(e) });
});)}
```

it return

```
    UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(): 400 ERROR Error: BotFrameworkAdapter.parseRequest(): missing activity type.
```

I've already check if the bot have the correct appId and pwd, and it's are ok.

This is my index.js file:

```js
// index.js is used to setup and configure your bot
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// Import required bot services.
// See https://aka.ms/bot-services to learn more about the different parts of a bot.
const { BotFrameworkAdapter } = require('botbuilder');
// Import bot definitions
const { BotActivityHandler } = require('./botActivityHandler');
// Read botFilePath and botFileSecret from .env file.
const ENV_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '.env');
require('dotenv').config({ path: ENV_FILE });
// Create adapter.
const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    appPassword: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
});
adapter.onTurnError = async (context, error) => {
    console.error(`unhandled error: ${error}`);
    console.dir(`unhandled error: ${error}`);
    await context.sendTraceActivity(
        'OnTurnError Trace',
        `${error}`,
        'https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error',
        'TurnError'
    );
    await context.sendActivity('The bot encountered an error or bug.');
    await context.sendActivity('To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code.');
};
// Create bot handlers
const botActivityHandler = new BotActivityHandler();
// Create HTTP server.
const server = express();
server.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    next();
});
server.use(bodyParser.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
}));
const port = process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978;
server.listen(port, () =>
    console.log(`service listening at https://localhost:${port}`)
);
// Listen for incoming requests.
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    console.dir(adapter);
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (context) => {
        // Process bot activity
        console.dir(context);
        await botActivityHandler.run(context).catch((e) => { console.dir(e) });
    });
});
server.post('/api/create/uat', (req, res) => {
    console.dir(req.params);
});
server.get('/api/read/uat', (req, res) => {
    console.dir(req.params);
});
server.post('/api/prova/post', (req, res) => {
    console.dir(req.params);
});
```

Locally with ngrok it run ok, Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: What payload are you using to test the POST endpoint? are you using the bot framework emulator, or connecting it to Microsoft Teams, or something like that?

Comment: Hi, I don't sure to understand what have you ask me. I launch the app from local web teams with visual studio code. The call is made from app to the azure endpoint where the "service" is deployed. You refer to this?

Comment: You say "...when I try to call the post url" - I want to check if you're making a call directly (like postman), or if you mean making the call from Teams, with the bot installed

Comment: I've try in both of case and the result is the same. From web teams app (started from local as described above with visual studio code) or from postman if I post to azurewebsiter.net url it return: 400 error described above

Comment: well, it sounds like you're NOT using a proper "bot" call - the payload needs to contain an element of type "activity". I would suggest connecting to it with bot framework emulator to see what gets sent/received.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to learn and try it. I have another doubt, when I deploy the app on another Azure web app, I can't connect to the already deployed "service" node to use it? They must be able to connect to each other, otherwise how could the Teams app work? I think I have missed some instructions. Now I've one app node.js for bot operation and another web app for tabs can you explain to me or connect me where I can learn how it works?

Comment: in the Azure portal, for your bot, under the "Settings", is where you tell the bot framework where the real endpoint is hosted, for your bot - maybe that answers your question. You can change it as you move the hosting (even to 'move' your bot from local workstation to production hosting, by changing this address).

Comment: Hi, I have already tried to change it and set the blue endpoint, where node.js is deployed, but as I described above, return me the error 400. Changing the endpoint from the "settings" menu is the first option I tried, when i saw the return, i tried calling it by postman, but it returns the same error. If I set up the local node.js endpoint, it works fine.

Comment: Hi @Leonardo, Please once try to connect to bot framework emulator and check.

Comment: Hi @Leonardo did the issue got resolved?

Comment: @Leonardo, in case you still face the issue, please drop a mail at microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com so that we can discuss further over call

Comment: Hi @ Saonti-MSFT, I solved it by deleting the local app and also the distributed app and then setting it as a new app (changing the url and for try put the bot id and pwd into the node.js code). Now the local web app correctly calls node.js (distributed app) and gets the response. In a few days I will try if both apps (once the web reaction part is distributed) are able to communicate with each other without the error. If I get the same error, I'll come back here and write a new comment, okay?

Comment: @Leonardo,That Sounds good

Comment: @Leonardo Moving your resolution as an Answer, for a better visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Leonardo, Local and distributed app can be deleted and setup a new app by changing the URL.